# useful c++ library for numeric calculation

Tags: c++, numerical-analysis, c-libraries

I've used boost library so far.

But, I'd like to use matrix operation and random numbers.

Please, let me know useful c++ library.

thanks.

Comment: Why not [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) and [Boost.Matrix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm)?

Comment: C++11 includes good random number generators. For linear algebra you could use Boost.UBLAS or Blitz++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really love the [GSL library.](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/)  although there are also the following, all of which are very good and very powerful:

- [Armadillo C++ linear algebra library](http://arma.sourceforge.net/)
- [Blitz++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blitz/)
- [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)
- [IT++](http://itpp.sourceforge.net/current/)

You can also check out a bigger list [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#C.2B.2B) However if you prefer boost, you can use [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) and [Boost.Matrix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm).